# Yubikey php integration

Tags: php, authentication

so I have been using Yubikey for a while and now want to integrate it to my admin section.

I have found a great class here: http://code.google.com/p/yubikey-php-webservice-class

the only problem is, it checks for a:

[yubikeytest.php]

```
if (md5 (substr ($otp, 0, 12).":".$_POST['username']) != $token_id)
```

Which means that the i must already have a token id in the database.

But i cant figure out how to create the original token and place it in the database since $token_id must = an md5 hash of the OTP and the username but we all know otp is ONE TIME and therefore will never = the original token.

am i doing something wrong and how would i be able to implement this with least trouble as possible?

What i want to do is keep my current auth, but for those users who have/want to auth with yubiekey, they can register their key with us <- I want to know how and then each login, those users, during login, will be asked to input the yubiekey OTP.

Please help and once I get a proper solution, I will make it accessible to any other users to make the process easier since this topic does not have much info.

PS. also if what I'm looking for is already in a script please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The YubiKey OTP is constructed of two parts, the last 32 characters being the encrypted OTP, the characters before that (by default 12) is a static public id, identifying the key. So the code above only does md5 of the public id, which you can get from any OTP from a given key.

For a php solution there is also the php-yubico project maintained by Yubico: http://code.google.com/p/php-yubico/

Comment: See that's what I meant, I did not find that in any of the documentation I've read. So that means, during registration, I should get the users public id and username and hash them together and store them in the database? ans just use this script to compare them. Also is it bad if i store them public id separately in the database instead of hashing on input... I want to be able to implement it in other methods for future use.

Comment: It's usually considered ok to store public id by it's own, more or less a username equivalent.